# Encoding Method for URLs?

Tags: plugin-development, api

Is there a method or API that WordPress uses to encode the URLs similar to how it generates part of the URL when using the title in the URL? I am writing a plugin that generates URLs and would like to use the same method as everything else is.

For instance, I type "This is my blog post" in the title and "this-is-my-blog-post" gets generated.

Comment: You mean you want to have generate slugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a lower level, the function `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` converts to lowercase, replaces spaces and non-alphanumeric characters with dashes, and urlencodes whatever you pass to it.

```
<?php

echo sanitize_title_with_dashes( 'This is my blog post' );
// this-is-my-blog-post
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for at the time. I ended up writing a string replace function to get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Post slugs seem to be generated by `wp_unique_post_slug()` function ([source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2518)).